# A flag does not appear in stats

Tags: bug, flagging, statistics

I have recently flagged a [question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3014/what-does-put-the-harbs-back-in-the-closet-mean). My name is listed in "closed as off-topic by..." users list.
However, the flag does not show up in [my profile](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/1009).

It only happened here. Other SE sites worked as expected.

If it helps, all previous flags were made via review, if I remember correctly, but this one was flagged from the question page.

Is it a bug or do I misunderstand the meaning of stats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reputation threshold for voting to close here is currently 500, you're at 682 when I'm answering to your Meta question, so [you have the privilege](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions).

If you have this privilege or power, but you still flag and choose "Off topic...", then your flag will not be counted as a flag, rather it will be converted to a close-vote. That's why you appear in the close-voters' list and you have no flags for the post.

For the future, if you have the privilege, you can just vote to close instead of flagging. If the question needs immediate attention, then you can close and flag it with the reason you deem appropriate for the situation, but close-voting is enough in other cases.

And if you think the question deserves closing but it's not gaining enough close-votes, then you can flag. What I mean is, there's no reason to flag everything, consider each case and see if a VTC + flag is appropriate or not.

Comment: Thank you. That's why the last flag is dated Dec/12 when my rep was 490. :)

Comment: @bytebuster Yep. :)